# Angular rxjs replaysubject not subscribed to observable

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have a service where i emit a value to a replaysubject observable as below. MyService.update() is called from app initializer.

```
Service:

    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class MyService {
            private _userSubject$ = new ReplaySubject<UserDetails>(1);
            user$: Observable<UserDetails> = this._userSubject$;
            test$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('test');

    constructor() {
         this.user$.subscribe((x) => console.log('it subscribes here'))
    }
            

    
            update(details: SessionDetailsResponse): void {
                this._userSubject$.next(details.userDetails);
                this.test$.next('updated');
            }   
        }
```

Component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.user$
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unSubscribe$))
            .subscribe((u) => {
                console.log('u', u); //not coming here
                this.currentUserId = u.id; //this is not subscribing here.
            });

      this.sessionDetails.test$
        .subscribe(x => {
            console.log('test', x); //this one subsribig with only default value and not the updated value.
        })
    }
```

Not sure why it is not subscribing.Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not subscribing"? You do subscribe.

Comment: i am subscribing i the component but it is not coming inside subscribe. Only when i subscribe in the same service it gets subscribed and not in the component. I am expecting to get it subscribed in both places when this._userSubject$.next is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. The service has already been decorated as ProvidedIn: Root as singleton service. In addition to this i have added to providers array of the module. Due to this the constructor is called twice and the values are lost.